# In a repo containing multiple packages, what should the version of each represent?

Tags: npm, versioning, package.json, semantic-versioning

I'm developing a web application whereby a React `client` application and Node Express `server` API live in the same repository, but with separate `package.json` files. The structure is as follows:

```
root
-client/
  --src/     
  --package.json  // manages create-react-app dependencies, scripts
-controllers/
-models/
-routes/
-app.js
-package.json // manages node express server dependencies, scripts
```

Seemingly, these separate packages are sub-modules of a system (ie of the web application). For example, consider the way routing is handled where any request that the server doesn't recognize is handled by a `client` router:

```
// app.js

require('./routes/...')(app)      // api routes defined first

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))
  const path = require('path')
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {   // non match fall through to client
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}
```

The server API does not have cors enabled.

Should these `package.json` files share the same version, or be versioned separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each package should be versioned separately. Tying them to the same version number means a simple bug fix in one, requires a meaningless version bump in the other.  Don't lie to your customers! A package version number applies to its contents and only its contents. Even a package of packages should have its own version sequence.

Optionally, you could simply ship a single package instead.

Comment: I think I already see the value - for example if I drop the React client for a new Vue or FooX.js one in the future, the server API remains while the client semantics have changed. Furthermore another client can be added (such as a mobile client) or server ops/logistics could change such the client can no longer be served from the same domain and thus decoupling the two packages even further.

Am I interpreting this in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like it.  The key to understanding versioning is to understand exactly what it is you are tracking with that number. Large monolithic packages with lots of bits inside are fairly brittle in practice. Fix some customer critical bug in a corner that most of your customers don't ever use and you wind up forcing everybody to take and install the whole thing.  But then, sometimes you want to package a bunch of packages (each individually versioned of course), so you can say here's a version set we tested and provide full support for.

Comment: `But then, sometimes you want to package a bunch of packages (each individually versioned of course), so you can say here's a version set we tested and provide full support for` - This should exist, exactly as written, in Fundamentals of Software Engineering textbooks. Thank you for the insight.